# Tunnel internet connectivity to one specific LAN port

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, tunnel

### Structure:

The main computer is a desktop computer with Ubuntu 18.04 and a dGPS (differential Global Positioing System) is connected to one of the LAN ports (enp2s0f1). The main computer receives permanent GPS data over this ethernet connection. Furthermore, a 4G USB network adapter is connected via USB, which provides an internet connection.

### Goal:

To tunnel/forward the internet connection, which is provided by the USB network adapter, to the LAN port enp2s0f1. The computer should not have any connection to the Internet. An internet connection is needed because the dGPS gets access to necessary correction data via the internet.

### IP structure:

[image: screenshot]

Which approaches (keywords) should I follow to solve my problem? Does anyone have a concrete solution?

Comment: Enabled forwarding, and NAT the segment to the dGPS. Tutorials should be easy to google.

Comment: Sounds like policy routing is what you need. By puting a/the default route to an alternate route table and having a ip rule that looks up the table only for traffics from a specific network interface and/or source ip/subnet, you should be able to avoid the computer itself from gaining Internet access.